# Start Date and End Date in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap datepicker to for an input field "start date" . If the field is empty, another field "end date", which is also filled using a datepicker, should be disabled. Only after entering a date in the start date, the end date field should be enabled. I tried doing this using angular js. The sample code is below.

Start date

```
<input ng-model="startdate"/>
```

End date

```
<input ng-disabled="!(!!startdate)"
```

The end date remains disabled even after selecting a start date. Please help. If I try to get the value of the start date field it says "htmlinput element"

Please help

Comment: take a look at my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty easy!!

Try this out

**[Working Demo 1](http://jsfiddle.net/ntaUJ/107/)**
**[Working Demo 2](http://plnkr.co/edit/De3mh8XLACb4XpS4syoZ?p=preview)**

```
Start Date :<input ng-model="startdate"/>
End Date :<input ng-disabled="!startdate"/>
```

Comment: Yes. This works if we manually enter a value into the start date box. But, its not working if I enter a value from a calendar(bootstrap timepicker).

Comment: take a look at my Working Demo2 of the answer